# Download Manager for Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, firefox, download

I need some good download manager for Linux (like IDM on windows). I want it to be able to install a browser plugin too, which allows you to download movies from youtube or other sites easily. It should also make as many as connection possible.

Comment: I realize now that this doesn't say *which* browser you are using... that's actually quite important to this question since what works for one may not work for another.

Comment: @xenote I use firefox, but the main question is that I want a good download manager independent of my browser

Comment: unfortunately this is mostly plugin based... and plugins for one browser do not work on another.

Comment: It may be a good idea to update your question with a more specific set of features that you are looking for in a download manager.

Comment: Idm can really be installed in Ubuntu and its flavours as described by above users.That really works. But difficult for novice users. Here's a pure build of idm installed in wine/playonlinux with the same flavour of integration as enjoyed in Windows OS. As questioned by the user Am1rr3zA , the answer is below: https://youtu.be/srFUgNH_BQg Just copied a few files of windows to make things running.

Answer (score 7):

I find myself using [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) (was "downthemall") for my downloads. It's a Firefox plugin and thus available everywhere (a very important reason why I chose it). You can

- download all links / media in a page
- download each item with up to 10 connections
- and yes, you can download Facebook videos

Comment: Ya I familiar with DownThemALL but It don't do what I mean

Comment: I read DownTheMall

Comment: Is there a chrome version ?

Comment: I haven't found a good chrome extension for downloading, that's why I still have Firefox with DownThemAll

Comment: not one that works on linux anyways. there are some chrome extensions that are similar but they seem to be windows only.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest Fatrat - http://fatrat.dolezel.info - the best download manager I've come across myself.

The Jabber remote control feature is what I love the most in the software.

I'd urge everyone to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) (in the repositories) with the [FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/) plugin for Firefox.

Comment: can download movie uploaded in facebook like IDM with this downloader?

Comment: Not familiar with IDM, but I suspect this would be possible.  Its just a matter of knowing the correct URL of the video, which FlashGot should take care of for you

Answer (score 1):

There is [pyload](http://pyload.org), built on python.

http://pyload.org/screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You can try out flareGet, which is the fastest download manager for Linux. You can you flashgot for browser integration and video download
http://sourceforge.net/projects/flareget/

Comment: I can't understand your second sentence, I think it needs a fix.